# Limit involving free variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions

Mathematica 10.1.0 fails to compute the following limit:

```
Limit[Log[X]^(3/2)*(-1 - 1/Sqrt[Log[X]] + (1 + 2/Log[X]^2)^p*
        (1 + 1/Sqrt[Log[X/2 + X/Log[X]^2]])), 
  X -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {Element[p, Reals]}]
```

After ten seconds or so, it simply returns the unevaluated expression even though the limit is $\frac{1}{2}\ln 2$ irrespective of the value of $p$. I'm fairly sure that this is the case because:

- I've proven it in a proof assistant (Isabelle/HOL)
- Maple outputs the correct result
- Mathematica outputs the correct result if *any* concrete value is substituted for $p$

Is this some kind of fundamental restriction of Mathematica regarding free variables in expressions or am I missing something here? (Someone in the ##mathematica IRC channel claimed it worked fine in his Mathematica version, so perhaps the version is relevant?)

Comment: I too have noticed problems with simple limits in recent versions of Mathematica

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why *Mathematica* has problems,but if substitute `X->Exp[x]` then:

```
sol = FullSimplify[Log[X]^(3/2)*(-1 - 
1/Sqrt[Log[X]] + (1 + 2/Log[X]^2)^p*
(1 + 1/Sqrt[Log[X/2 + X/Log[X]^2]])) /. X -> Exp[x], Assumptions -> {Element[x, Reals]}]

(* x^(3/2) (-1 - 1/Sqrt[x] + (1 + 2/x^2)^p (1 + 1/Sqrt[x + Log[1/2 + 1/x^2]])) *)

Limit[sol, x -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {Element[p, Reals]}]

(*Log[2]/2*)
```

Comment: That's an interesting observation, thanks. I am, however, interested not in an ad-hoc way to make this particular example go through but rather in understanding what is going wrong here and how to fix it in general.

Comment: @ManuelEberl. Wolfram Technical Support can only fix it.

Comment: Well, by ‘fix’ I meant finding e.g. a different set of configuration options. I don't know Mathematica very well and thought I might have missed something. (Especially because someone on IRC claimed that the examples works fine with his version of Mathematica)

Comment: I'm have MMA version `10.2` and `11.0` both can't find solution.

Comment: Neither can `10.4.1`.